# Do I need mana in my mana pool to summon a creature card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there a limit to how many creatures I can summon in a turn?

Comment: It would help explain how this stuff works if you add some detail about how you think it works. Specifically, what do you already know about how creatures are cast?

Comment: The questions in the title and body are totally different. I think it would help if you chose one and expanded on it. Provide some context. For example, what prompted the question? What made you think that there may be a limit on how many creatures you can summon per turn? Also, try reading over the [Basic Rules](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/resources/rules/EN_MTGM14_PrintedRulebook_LR.pdf). They address most of the situations you'll need to know about as a casual player.

Answer (score 2):

Each spell that you cast has a mana cost associated with it. Whether creature, instant, planeswalker, or any other, they all have a mana cost. (Lands aren't spells, so they're treated different, but that's a topic for a different day.)

You must have mana in the necessary amount and type to cast the spell as indicated in the top right corner of the spell. If you want to cast a [Runeclaw Bear](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Runeclaw%20Bear) you must have two mana, one of which must be green. Simple stuff.

You do not necessarily need the mana to be in your pool at the time you *declare* the spell. You may declare a spell, then activate mana abilities (like [Forest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Forest) or [Mystic Druid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mystic%20Druid), but notably not [Arbor Elf](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arbor%20Elf) who normally serves the same purpose) if you so choose. It's worth noting that since no one can respond to mana abilities, this is effectively the same if you declare then pay or if you pay then declare. If you read up on Magic's history, it was once a hot point of contention!!

You may encounter creatures or other spells that require 0 mana. [Memnite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Memnite) comes to mind, along with [Black Lotus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Black%20Lotus). Clearly, you always have the appropriate mana to cast these spells. You may also encounter spells with no mana cost, like [Evermind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Evermind) but you'll find these to be the exception, and you're unlikely to find them in most scenarios.

As for a limit, generally you're only limited by the amount of mana you have available. Some obscure spells like [Rule of Law](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rule%20of%20Law) or [Æther Storm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=%C3%86ther%20Storm) will get in the way, but for most circumstances you're only limited by your mana. In fact, many strategies (particularly red decks) rely on getting 2 or even 3 creatures out a turn in an effort to swarm opponents before they can mount a viable defense.

Keep in mind that if you're unsure about these simple questions, while we're happy to help, you may want to find a knowledgeable IRL buddy to ask these to. This represents a fundamental uncertainty about core aspects of the game which will make playing it difficult and potentially un-fun. I highly recommend engaging your LGS about how to get practice with regular players so you don't learn wrong!

Comment: Heh, just in case you casually run into a Black Lotus...

Comment: Proxies... proxies everywhere!